# How to enter characters to a vector in a structure?

Tags: c++, string, struct, stdvector

I am making a program which requires me to enter characters, which I want to store in a `vector` declared inside a `struct`.

I have tried to enter the characters using a new variable of `char` type and `string` type but both did not work. It gives me `SIGSEGV` error while printing.

```
struct Student {
  int age, standard;
  vector<string> first_name;
  vector<char> last_name;
};

int main() {
  Student st;

  string k;

  cin >> st.age;
  getline(cin, k);

  st.first_name.push_back(k);

  cout << st.age << " " << endl;
  cout << "\t" << st.first_name.size() << endl;
  for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= st.first_name.size(); x++) {
    cout << st.first_name[x] << " ";
  }
}
```

When the input is:

```
11
lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn
```

the expected output is

```
11 lwpxiteeppsacowpnbxluqpmasgnwefzcsvrjxxammuqcftzgn
```

but I am getting an error instead.

Comment: Why `vector<char> last_name;`? And not simply `std::string last_name;`?

Comment: I can see a case for a `vector` of given names, but when you have many names only one can be first.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop is going out of bounds. You need to use `<` instead of `<=`:

```cpp
for(vector<string>::size_type x = 0; x < st.first_name.size(); ++x) {
    cout << st.first_name[x] << " ";
}
```

That being said, `std::vector<std::string>` does not make sense for `first_name`.  `std::vector<char>` would make more sense (like you do for `last_name`), though it would be MUCH better to use `std::string` instead:

```cpp
struct Student {
    int age,standard;
    //char first_name[51],last_name[51];
    string first_name, last_name;
};


int main() {
    Student st;

    string k;

    cin >> st.age;// >> st.last_name >> st.standard;
    getline(cin, k);

    st.first_name = k;

    cout << st.age << " " << endl;// << st.first_name << " ";// << st.last_name << " " << st.standard;
    cout << "\t" << st.first_name << endl;
}
```

Or, since you are using `std::getline()` to read a whole name, don't even separate `first_name` and `last_name` at all:

```cpp
struct Student {
    int age,standard;
    //char first_name[51],last_name[51];
    string name;
};


int main() {
    Student st;

    string k;

    cin >> st.age;// >> st.last_name >> st.standard;
    getline(cin, k);

    st.name = k;

    cout << st.age << " " << endl;// << st.first_name << " ";// << st.last_name << " " << st.standard;
    cout << "\t" << st.name << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the problem:

```
for (unsigned int x = 0; x <= st.first_name.size(); x++)
```

`<=` includes the size, which is out of bound. Use `<` or `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `<=` to `<`.

Or else it will be out of memory bound